# PNG relative path not displaying image in HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, png

I'm having trouble loading a single PNG image in my HTML. I have tried using the path, and the relative path to display this image to no avail. I know the other image is working in the images folder because it is currently displayed in the background of my application.

my code currently is,

```
            <div className="nba-logo">
            <img src="frontend/src/images/nba-logo-black-transparent.png" alt="nba logo" />
        </div>
```

I've also tried:

```
            <div className="nba-logo">
            <img src="../images/nba-logo-black-transparent.png" alt="nba logo" />
        </div>
```

and:

```
            <div className="nba-logo">
            <img src="./images/nba-logo-black-transparent.png" alt="nba logo" />
        </div>
```

to no avail.

My directory structure is,

```
frontend
   src
     components > footer.js <- 2nd img is linked using "../images./nba-logo-black-transparent.png"
     images >
     http > 
     app.js
     app.css <- background img is linked here using "./images/parallax-img.png"
     index.css
   node-modules
   etc...
```

Comment: It does, thank you! I forgot in React the src needs to imported.